# とどく; 届く meaning in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, verbs

と…とても信じられん…こ…この聖域にまでパワーがとどくなんて

Unbelievable! That the power would reach even this sanctuary...!

Looking for an in depth explanation of the usage of とどく; 届く here, because I've read that it means reach as a movement verb that's synonymous with "arrive", and what it means contextually for the subject here "パワー"

Answer (score 1):

It should just mean 'to arrive/reach'.

I suppose the sentence comes from somewhere later in Dragon Ball (super saiyan 3?), where the power='気' is described as a kind of wave (like かめはめ**波**).

The stronger/larger 気 is, the farther it is felt. So the sentence is saying that the power is so strong to be felt even in the remotest place where the speaker is.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and yes, it is indeed Super Saiyan 3! I see, so the context given would be that the power wave travelled to and reached/arrived at the speaker's location hence being felt there?

Comment: @ssj_janessa Yup. It's basically the same as saying, about a wave, a thing like *the tsunami caused by an earthquake in Chile reached Japan*. Literally  - *Can't believe it. The (wave caused by) power reaches as far as this (remote) sacred place.*